# How to change SharePoint web application port number?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I have created a web application for intranet zone. I want to know how to change the port number of the web application? Could I change it directly in IIS manager (is this way safe)?

Answer (score 3):

Extend your existing web application to a new port ( CA > Application Mgmt > Extend an existing web application > apply new port and/or host header).

You can then delete the old web application using CA.

hth
Anders Rask

Comment: "Another option is to use" -- what is the other option?

Comment: If previous default zone is using port 80, how to make a new zone using port 80 by using extension solution as you mentioned? Since port 80 is occupied. Appreciate if you could describe in more detailed steps.

Comment: ah sorry forgot to delete. Was about to write about how to use STSADM.EXE to do the same thing.
If the zone already has port 80, why do you want to change it? It sounds like your problem is that you want to change zones?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting IIS site will make you loose all your customizations including web.config changes. So Don't do it!

There is an easiest way to change SharePoint Web Application Port by updating IIS bindings and Alternate Access Mappings. Find the detailed instructions here: [How to Change Sharepoint Web Application Port](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/09/how-to-change-sharepoint-web-application-port.html)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change it in IIS and in the Alternate Access Mappings in Central Admin.

Comment: Is it totally safe? No impact for backup/restore (not sure whether DB stores the port number, if so, then if I only change IIS, DB will be inconsistent)?

Comment: Previously, I am using IP address for intranet zone in alternative access mapping, and now I want to use IP address for extranet zone. Then I should change in alternative access mapping to map IP address to extranet zone, other than intranet zone?

Comment: -1: Changes should never be made directly in IIS. Only SharePoint Central Administration should be used if possible.

Comment: But how to change port in Central ADministration Console?